# How do I make sure every character in a string argv[1] is digit in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I was doing an encryption exercise in CS50, and I got stuck
There is this part: "**Add to caesar.c, below main, a function called, e.g., only_digits that takes a string as an argument and returns true if that string contains only digits, 0 through 9, else it returns false. Be sure to add the function’s prototype above main as well**".

And here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument

    argc = only_digits(argv[1]);
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

// make sure that the character in argv[1] is a digit

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    // int n = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I decided to make a for loop, where I could check whether the characters are digits, but I need only to check the second character, not "caesar", and because of that, I presume, my code fails and comes with "Usage: ./caesar key\n" all the time, and if I write only "./caesar" - it comes with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Apparently my code is flawed, but I can't find the solution to it.

Comment: What should `argc = only_digits(argv[1]);` do? You don't want to overwrite `argc`.

Comment: Your first problem is, if you run “caesar” without any parameters argv[1] will be NULL, which you are passing to only_digits().

Comment: `I need only to check the second character, not "caesar"` - I do not understand this. `"caesar"` is not a character. It is a string and would be the first argument i.e. `argv[0]`, if the program were even ran as `caesar`, and not `./caesar`, as the usage suggests. Aside from the problem already noted, your issue is that you immediately return once the first character of your argument is a digit. You should only return if all of them were. Your program failing with the usage text is definitely not because of you checking wrong characters, since you aren't checking them at that point.

Comment: @Larry is correct; only_digits() (which should be called after the argc != 2 check) only checks the first digit of argv[1], not the whole string. Also, by convention a boolean function should return 0 if false, non-zero if true; only_digits() does the opposite. And why argc is used to store its return?

Comment: Thank you, ya'll! Yup, it was really strange to reuse argc in such way, and I did not know about true as non-zero and false as 0 in booleans. Many thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's note a few mistakes/misuse.

- You can do this but I discourage you to.. Leave the `argc` aside. I mean, do not reuse it for something else. Create a dedicated variable instead..
- Always check for validity of input argument(s) before processing them. In your case, when the user gives no input you still check for number. The makes you access invalid memory area and can trigger a segmentation fault.
- In the example code you provide, `only_digits` either returns `0` or `1`. Thus, checking `if(argc != 2)` always gets satisfied.
- Your function `only_digits` is supposed to return a boolean => either `true` (or `1`) or `false` (or `0`). By convention, during your learning process, I advice you to stick to `true` and `false`.
- Your function `only_digits` has a negated logic. It will return true if it has non digit only.

The resulting code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    /* Make sure there are enough arguments passed to your program. */
    if (argc < 2) {
        goto usage;
    }

    // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument
    bool isvalid = only_digits(argv[1]);
    if(isvalid == 0) {
        goto usage;
    }

    // everything is good.
    return 0;

usage:
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
}

// make sure that the character in argv[1] is a digit

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        /* Here, we want to break the loop upon the first non-digit
         * character. Thus the negation `!` */
        if(!isdigit(s[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!
I had that feeling that I did it wrong with argc, I first thought that I might need to reuse it to check if the characters are digits, but that just wasn't what argc is meant for. Now that I see how stupid my mistake wass, I feel a little embarrassed

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you practically can re-use any variable. Concerning variables just keep in mind that having a dedicated variables with proper name help make your code more readable. The compiler will optimize at build time so, at your stage, don't bother with this. Keep learning and experimenting, you're on the right tracks!

Answer (score 0):

The OP code is trying to do too many things, and getting the order mixed up. For instance, the task of the function `only_digits()` is to test a string as being made up of only ASCII digits, not reporting how to execute the program.

Below uses less code. The characters of the passed parameter (if there is one) are checked. If there was a parameter, and there was 1+ characters to check, and the check reaches the end of the string, the return value is `true` signifying all is good.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

bool only_digits(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if( only_digits( argv[1] ) == 0 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* more code here */

    return 0;
}

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( s && isdigit( s[i] ) )
        i++; // loop until end of string (if there is one)
    return s && i && s[i] == '\0';
}
```

One wants to write concise code that doesn't give room for bugs to hide.
This 'burns' a few extra (exceedingly cheap) machine cycles. Who cares?

**EDIT**
It's a little known fact that C guarantees that the "post-ultimate" value of argv[] will be NULL. (ie: "a.out foobar" sets argv[0] to point at "a.out", argv[1] to point at "foobar", and argv[2] to be NULL. One can use this information to one's advantage.

Comment: Many thanks, sir! Your explanation is really helpful, made me have some notes on better coding 